# extend controller inside HMVC Codeigniter module

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc, codeigniter-hmvc

**How do I extend a controller of a HMVC module within the module itself?**

```
class Backend extends Backend_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Assuming the following typical Codeigniter file structure as it relates to HMVC:

```
/
/application
/application/modules
/application/modules/backen
/application/modules/backen/controllers
/application/modules/backen/controllers/Backend.php
/application/modules/backen/libraries
/application/modules/backen/libraries/Backend_Controller.php
```

In this structure get the error "class not found". Works to put in the folder "/application/libraries/Backend_Controller.php".

Answer (score 2):

Controllers have to extend CI_Controller in CodeIgniter. Controllers cannot extend libraries but they can include them like this $this->load->library('backendLib');

If you are using Wiredesignz HMVC extension you can use base controllers for this. Just make a backend_controller class in the core directory and make it extend MX_Controller. Now you can make the module controller extend the backend_controller.

Best,

Bart

Answer (score 0):

Hi CI always look for core classes starts with CI_Controller or extended classes name started with MY_ like MY_Controller MY_Email etc if your any other class to be called not like library you can add the following code in config.php will autoload custom class

```
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Native spl_autoload_register() - by Kenneth Vogt
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is an updated version of Phil Sturgeon’s code:
|
| Thanks to Phil Sturgeon Kenneth Vogt and InsiteFX.
|
| NOTE:
| Requires PHP 5.3.+
| As of CI 3.0 Dev - The constant EXT has been removed modified
| to use '.php' now instead of EXT.
| should work for all version of CI and PHP 5.3
|
| Place at the bottom of your ./application/config/config.php file.
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

spl_autoload_register(function($class)
{
    if (strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
    {
        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . '.php'))
        {
            include $file;
        }
        elseif (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'libraries/' . $class . '.php'))
        {
            include $file;
        }
    }
});
```

reference from this fourm post thread
http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-473-post-2679.html#pid2679

now you can extend your controller with custom controller name Backend_Controller this class should available under application either library or core directory